# CAKeyFrameAnimation with Color from patternImage

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation, cgcolor

I am trying to animate the backgroundColor of a CALayer with CAKeyFrameAnimation.
When I make it with classics colors it works; But with Color generated from patternImage `UIColor(patternImage:"imageName").CGColor`, it doesn't work at all.

```
@IBAction func animFirstView(sender: AnyObject)
{
    addAnim(view1, colors: [UIColor.blackColor().CGColor, UIColor.redColor().CGColor]) // THAT WORKS 

}

@IBAction func animSecondView(sender: AnyObject)
{

    var firstColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"stars1")!).CGColor;
    addAnim(view2,
        colors: [firstColor]); // THAT doesn't works at all :(
}

func addAnim(view:UIView, colors:[CGColor])
{
    let anim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath:"backgroundColor")
          anim.values = colors;
    anim.keyTimes = [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1];
    anim.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete
    anim.duration = 0.3;
    anim.repeatCount = Float.infinity;
    view.layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "backgroundColor");

}
```

Someone has an idea?

Isn't it possible to do that or am I doing something wrong?

A test case of the "bug" https://github.com/lastMove/patternBugDemo

Comment: Thank you for posting the example at github! That gave me something to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why setting the `backgroundColor` to a pattern color as part of a keyframe animation doesn't work. I solved this by imitating [my own existing example](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch04p149keyframeSprite/ch17p495keyframeSprite/ViewController.swift) where I set the `contents` as a keyframe animation:

```
@IBAction func animSecondView(sender: AnyObject)
{
    var firstColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"stars1")!)
    var secondColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"stars2")!)
    addAnim(view2,
        colors: [firstColor, secondColor, firstColor, secondColor]);
}

func addAnim(view:UIView, colors:[UIColor])
{
    let anim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath:"contents")
    anim.values = colors.map {
        col in
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, true, 0)
        col.setFill()
        UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds).fill()
        let im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return im.CGImage
    }
    anim.keyTimes = [0.0, 0.25, 0.75, 1.0];
    anim.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete
    anim.duration = 1;
    anim.repeatCount = Float.infinity;
    view.layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: nil);
}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Here's another workaround: keep using the layer background color, but change it directly, with a timer:

```
@IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
var colors = [UIColor]()
var timer : NSTimer!
var second = false

@IBAction func animSecondView(sender: AnyObject)
{
    var firstColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"stars1")!)
    var secondColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"stars2")!)
    self.colors = [firstColor, secondColor]
    if let timer = self.timer {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "anim:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
func anim(t:NSTimer) {
    view2.layer.backgroundColor = self.colors[self.second ? 1 : 0].CGColor
    self.second = !self.second
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for this. But i really need to do it on a color. 
In my project i am loading SVG into CAShapeLayer and I can easily put pattern images into those shapeLayers with 
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor(patternImage:"image").CGColor.
Now i want to make the same with multiples images like a gif.
So I don't think  that i can use the contents property. Except if i add another sublayer with a mask on the main layerm but it seems very heavy.
I will certainly create a bugReport and/or a ticket.

Comment: I think you're completely wrong about "heavy". Repeatedly changing the `backgroundColor` or repeatedly changing the `contents` (possibly of another layer) is no more or less work as far as the render server is concerned! I agree with your bug report idea, but I think you should just go ahead and use this workaround if we can't find another way.

Comment: The thing that seems heavy to me is not the animation. It the fact to add each time a sublayer + a mask.
I will try to apply your workaround with fill Color. The advantage of fillColor is that it fills only the layer's path. So i have to found how to mimics that with your way.

Comment: By the way, did you notice in your project that not only does it not work with the `backgroundColor` being a pattern, but the project actually hangs? Watch the button when you tap it. If you do plain colors, the button turns grey and then back to blue. But if you do patterns, the button turns grey and stays there. This tells me that we are causing the whole render server to get hung up.

Comment: I am sympathetic but I really think you are optimizing prematurely. Try it and _see_ if there is a problem. I use layers / masks all the time, sometimes many of them, lying on top of each other. If there's a problem, you'll get "stuttering" (esp. when testing on the device) when the render server frame rate slows down; this can happen e.g. when scrolling a table whose cells are too render-heavy. But if it is just sitting there, I don't believe there will be any problem.

Comment: By the way, I also tried UIView keyframe animation instead of Core Animation keyframe animation, but it didn't change anything. (I didn't expect it would; the background color of a UIView is the background color of its CALayer, and all animation is ultimately Core Animation layer animation.)

Comment: I am making a  game. based on SVGKit. And I am animating the svgs layers (they are moving, rotating, scaling etc) and sometimes when i put to many sublayers/animation i have FPS drops. 
But you are right, i shouldn't optimize prematurely. I am trying your solution directly on my base project.

Comment: I have another workaround: use an NSTimer and change the layer background color directly. Posting it now...

Comment: I don't really like the NSTimer workaround. 
I will use your first one. thank you. I filed a bug to apple.

Comment: Thanks; it might or might not be a bug, but it is not exactly intuitive behavior, and I'm glad you filed it. Let's see what Apple does!